# jQuery Validate money field, accept spaces?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a custom validator for money fields, it accepts values like

```
12,00$
122.04$
12123123
```

Now, I want to make it accept theese values:

```
1 200$
1 200,22$
```

So accept spaces. And unfortunately, I'm not very good at regex.

Here's my custom validator:

```
$.validator.addMethod("money", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^\$?(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{1,2})?)\s?\$?$/);
}, "Not valid...");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\$?(\d+(?:\s\d+)*(?:[\.\,]\d{1,2})?)\s?\$?$
```

I have only added `(?:\s\d+)*` to your regex to allow any number of digits with spaces after an initial number. Mind you do not have to escape `.` and `,` inside the character class `[\.\,]` (it is equal to `[.,]`).

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH3oH4/4).

Try

```
$.validator.addMethod("money", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^\$?(\d+(?:\s\d+)*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?)\s?\$?$/);
}, "Not valid...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex.

```
^\$?\d+(?:[ ,]\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\$?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gV8gW7/2)